# Neo4j cypher query to get all nodes without a relationship to specific other node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I use Neo4j 2.3.1 and looking I am looking for a cypher query which gives me all nodes in the database which are not connected to the specific other node.
My Tree looks like this:

[image]

I know the red one and want to have a query which gives me the green ones. All of them do have the same relationship.

EDIT: My question is misleading worded, so: What I want (as shown in the image) all nodes which are "above" a specific node and also their childs.

Comment: In general, a graph DB can have multiple disjoint subgraphs (which do not even have to be trees). For example, imagine that here are additional nodes that are not connected in any way to your tree. Do you also want nodes in disjoint subgraphs and their relationships?

Comment: the green node above your red node is connected to the red node ... so your statement in itself is inconsistent :)

Comment: @MichaelHunger - yes you are right, my description and the picture does not show the same thing - i will change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH (red)<-[*]-(parent)-[*0..10]->(children)
WHERE red.id = xxx
RETURN parent, children
```

Find all of the parents of the red node and all children of the parents.

Comment: As cypher doesn't traverse a relationship twice this should be most efficient.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot and it is very fast.

Answer (score 2):

In general, a graph DB can have multiple disjoint subgraphs (which do not even have to be trees). For example, suppose there are additional nodes that are not connected in any way to your subgraph.

Here is one way you can get *all* nodes that are not connected to a specified node via forward `REL` relationships. I assume that the interesting nodes all have the same label (`Foo`) and that there are other nodes without that label.

```
MATCH (n:Foo { id: 123 })-[:REL*]->(m:Foo)
WITH (COLLECT(DISTINCT m) + n) AS not_wanted
MATCH (x:Foo)
WHERE NOT x IN not_wanted
RETURN x;
```

Note: This query can take a very long time (or run out of memory), depending on big the "tree" rooted at `n` is and how many nodes there are in the DB. You should omit the node labels that do not help you filter out anything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Nice idea to return also the nodes which don't have any relation. The query is working well and returns me the correct result, but, as you said, the query is very slow, for 17000 nodes it takes a few minutes..

Answer (score 0):

Depends. Assuming that all of your node labels are the same, this should work:

```
   MATCH (a:circle)-[r]->(b:circle)
    WHERE a.colour <> 'Red' AND b.colour <> 'Red'
    RETURN a,b
```

Comment: The color was just for visualization - I do not know the color ;-) I only know the ID of the "red" node and want to have all nodes which are not childs of this node.

Comment: What makes each node different? Is it the labels or the properties on each node that makes it a different colour? The answer depends on what the data actually is.

Comment: Forget the colour - All of the nodes have the same label and are connected with the same relationshiptype. As I said, i just have the ID of one node and want to have all nodes in the tree which are "above" this node. I search for something like this: `match (n)<-[r:REL*0..]-(m) where n.id = xxx return m;` and additionally all the children of the m's.